Why does my code snippet of an JSON file work but the full JSON load does not
I have a snippet of JSON file that I normalize and use record_path on with the meta parameters on other columns and it works fine, but when I load the whole file I get a key error.  Below is my code for the snippet and full json download file load.
Snippet Works
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "meta": {
        "disclaimer": "Do not rely on openFDA to make decisions regarding medical care. While we make every effort to ensure that data is accurate, you should assume all results are unvalidated. We may limit or otherwise restrict your access to the API in line with our Terms of Service.",
        "terms": "https://open.fda.gov/terms/",
        "license": "https://open.fda.gov/license/",
        "last_updated": "2024-11-15",
        "results": {
            "skip": 0,
            "limit": 2,
            "total": 118943
        }
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "product_ndc": "73647-062",
            "generic_name": "MENTHOL, CAMPHOR",
            "labeler_name": "Just Brands LLC",
            "brand_name": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CAMPHOR (SYNTHETIC)",
                    "strength": "2 g/100g"
                },
                {
                    "name": "MENTHOL",
                    "strength": "6 g/100g"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "73647-062-04",
                    "description": "113 g in 1 BOTTLE, PUMP (73647-062-04)",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "listing_expiration_date": "20251231",
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Just Brands LLC"],
                "spl_set_id": ["f664eb79-8897-3a49-e053-2995a90a37b4"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["5TJD82A1ET", "L7T10EIP3A"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "OTC MONOGRAPH DRUG",
            "dosage_form": "GEL",
            "spl_id": "16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "product_type": "HUMAN OTC DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20230314",
            "product_id": "73647-062_16c906dd-6989-9a79-e063-6394a90afa71",
            "application_number": "M017",
            "brand_name_base": "JUST CBD - CBD AND THC ULTRA RELIEF"
        },
        {
            "product_ndc": "0591-4039",
            "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
            "generic_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "labeler_name": "Actavis Pharma, Inc.",
            "brand_name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "active_ingredients": [
                {
                    "name": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
                    "strength": ".05 g/mL"
                }
            ],
            "finished": True,
            "packaging": [
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-46",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-46)  / 59 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                },
                {
                    "package_ndc": "0591-4039-74",
                    "description": "1 BOTTLE in 1 CARTON (0591-4039-74)  / 125 mL in 1 BOTTLE",
                    "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
                    "marketing_end_date": "20250930",
                    "sample": False
                }
            ],
            "openfda": {
                "manufacturer_name": ["Actavis Pharma, Inc."],
                "rxcui": ["861512"],
                "spl_set_id": ["907e425a-720a-4180-b97c-9e25008a3658"],
                "is_original_packager": [True],
                "unii": ["779619577M"]
            },
            "marketing_category": "NDA AUTHORIZED GENERIC",
            "dosage_form": "SPRAY",
            "spl_id": "33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "product_type": "HUMAN PRESCRIPTION DRUG",
            "route": ["TOPICAL"],
            "marketing_start_date": "20150828",
            "product_id": "0591-4039_33a56b8b-a9a6-4287-bbf4-d68ad0c59e07",
            "application_number": "NDA021835",
            "brand_name_base": "CLOBETASOL PROPIONATE",
            "pharm_class": [
                "Corticosteroid Hormone Receptor Agonists [MoA]",
                "Corticosteroid [EPC]"
            ]
        }
    ]
}

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["packaging"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["active_ingredients"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

combined_data = pd.merge(
    packaging_data,
    active_ingredients_data,
    on=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name'],
    how='outer'
)

full download and load of JSON file gives a key error when using meta
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests, zipfile, io, os

cwd = os.getcwd()
zip_url = 'https://download.open.fda.gov/drug/ndc/drug-ndc-0001-of-0001.json.zip'
r = requests.get(zip_url)
z = zipfile.ZipFile(io.BytesIO(r.content))
z.extractall(cwd)

with open('drug-ndc-0001-of-0001.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["packaging"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data['results'], 
    record_path=["active_ingredients"], 
    meta=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name']
)

combined_data = pd.merge(
    packaging_data,
    active_ingredients_data,
    on=['product_ndc', 'brand_name', 'generic_name'],
    how='outer'
)


Post the full error message so we can make sure we see the same thing. I downloaded your dataset - not all records have a "brand_name" or "active_ingredients". What do you want to happen in those cases? You could set errors='ignore' to fill in null for brand_name but active_ingredients is tricky because its your path. Perhaps you could preprocess the records to fill in missing data with defaults.

You could delete a lot of the data in your working example. Then find places in your real data where the fields are missing and add in a few fake records with the same error pattern. Now you have a simple, failing test case. And you can reduce the amount of code to demonstrate.

I put the errors='ignore' and now the packaging_data processed correctly and gave me blanks on the observations with no brand name.   Now i get "KeyError: "Key 'active_ingredients' not found"  I just normalized the whole dataset without record_path and I now see that I have some entries with no active ingredients.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  If you want to post your answer instead of a comment I will mark it as answered.

You have holes in your data. Some records don't have a "brand_name", others are missing the "active_ingredients" list used to expand the table. For "brand_name" you can set errors='ignore' to fill a default value. If you don't like that solution, you can prescan the list and modify those records yourself.
"active_ingredients" is more problematic. That field needs to exist as a list in all records. You could scan those records and either add an empty list or remove the record completely, depending on how you want to solve the problem.

You need to allow for missing meta keys and "active_ingredients". In the case of the meta keys I would just add "n/a" (not available) and in the latter case just use an empty list.
When downloading large content, I prefer to stream.
Therefore, I suggest:
import requests
from zipfile import ZipFile
import json
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

CHUNK = 4096
META = ["product_ndc", "brand_name", "generic_name"]
DEFAULTS = {
    "product_ndc": "n/a",
    "brand_name": "n/a",
    "generic_name": "n/a",
    "active_ingredients": []
}
url = "https://download.open.fda.gov/drug/ndc/drug-ndc-0001-of-0001.json.zip"
filename = Path(url.split("/")[-1])

with requests.get(url, stream=True) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    with filename.open("wb") as z:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(CHUNK):
            z.write(chunk)

with ZipFile(filename) as z:
    z.extractall()
    with Path(z.namelist()[0]).open() as j:
        data = json.load(j)
    for result in data["results"]:
        for key, value in DEFAULTS.items():
            result.setdefault(key, value)

packaging_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data["results"], record_path=["packaging"], meta=list(META) # call list() to satisfy mypy
)

active_ingredients_data = pd.json_normalize(
    data["results"], record_path=["active_ingredients"], meta=list(META) # call list() to satisfy mypy
)

combined_data = pd.merge(packaging_data, active_ingredients_data, on=META, how="outer")

print(combined_data.head())

Output:
    package_ndc                                 description marketing_start_date sample marketing_end_date product_ndc brand_name   generic_name           name     strength
0  0002-0013-03   3 mL in 1 VIAL, MULTI-DOSE (0002-0013-03)            04-DEC-09    NaN                NaN   0002-0013        n/a  Insulin human  INSULIN HUMAN  100 [iU]/mL
1  0002-0013-10  10 mL in 1 VIAL, MULTI-DOSE (0002-0013-10)            27-JUN-83    NaN                NaN   0002-0013        n/a  Insulin human  INSULIN HUMAN  100 [iU]/mL
2  0002-0095-00            3 mL in 1 SYRINGE (0002-0095-00)            29-DEC-15    NaN                NaN   0002-0095        n/a  Insulin human  INSULIN HUMAN  500 [iU]/mL
3  0002-0096-00  20 mL in 1 VIAL, MULTI-DOSE (0002-0096-00)            06-JAN-97    NaN                NaN   0002-0096        n/a  Insulin human  INSULIN HUMAN  500 [iU]/mL
4  0002-0113-03   3 mL in 1 VIAL, MULTI-DOSE (0002-0113-03)            24-JUN-10    NaN                NaN   0002-0113        n/a  Insulin human  INSULIN HUMAN  100 [iU]/mL

